# symfony2 routing, optional prefix from database

Tags: database, symfony, routes

Basically what i want to achieve is this:

I have this paths:

http://SITENAME/dashboard

http://SITENAME/users

And they are mapped to the right controllers and actions:

```
/**
 * @Route("/dashboard")
 */
public function dashboardAction()
{
    // handle the request
}

/**
 * @Route("/users")
 */
public function usersAction()
{
    // handle the request
}
```

Now I want to make these other paths to map to the same controllers and actions:

http://SITENAME/{companyName}/dashboard

http://SITENAME/{companyName}/users

*companyName* is a name that I check on db if exists and if not throw a NotFound Exception.

These paths will just add some filter to the queries made, basically showing the same data structure.

I know I can create other actions and put those after the previous ones in order to be catched but I'm asking if there's something clever... something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/({companyName}/)dashboard")
 */
public function dashboardAction($companyName = null)
{
    // handle the request
}
```

where companyName is optional.

Thanks...

**UPDATE**

As Manolo suggested I already tried something like this and it works:

```
/**
 * @Route("/dashboard")
 * @Route("/{companyName}/dashboard")
 */
public function dashboardAction($companyName = null)
{
    // handle the request
}
```

But I think there's a clever way of handling it...

Comment: What about a paramconverter for the companyName?

Comment: Hi Matteo. Would you explain what do you mean? Thanks...

Comment: Hi, i try with an answer,

Answer (score 2):

Look at this example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#routing-with-placeholders

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/BlogController.php

// ...

/**
 * @Route("/blog/{page}", defaults={"page" = 1})
 */
public function indexAction($page)
{
    // ...
}
```

When page is not defined in the route, it is equal to 1.

But this won't work in your case, because you defined two routes for the same action:

`/dasboard`

`/{companyName}/dashboard`

So you have two options:

**1. Define two routes for the same action (weird).**

**2. Change your defined route to: `/dashboard/{companyName}` (better)**

Then, you can get `/dashboard` and `/dashboard/{companyName}` with the same action.

Comment: Hi Manolo... This is standard practice but not what I need. As i wrote, the (optional) parameter, for what i need, is not a the end of the path but at the beginning: "/({companyName}/)dashboard

Comment: You're right. You may define two routes for the same action, because they are two different routes: `/{companyName}/dashboard` and `/dashboard`.

Comment: Anyway, I recommend you to use `/dashboard/{companyName}`. It's more consistent.

Comment: Thanks Manolo. I've already done as you suggest (two different routes) and it works. I just think that maybe there's a clever or better way to handle it. I will edit my question to mark what you suggest as already tried.
About the path structure -> no way. This is the structure that i need to achieve and it is for several reasons that are outside of the scope. But thank you anyway!!!

Comment: Did you found any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{companyName}/dashboard")
 */
public function dashboardAction($companyName = null)
{
    // handle the request
}
```

Comment: I already tried this, but it's not good. While it handle paths like "/company1/dashboard" it fails to handle "/dashboard" (without the optional prefix)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the [@ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) annotation calls converters to convert request parameters to objects.

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;

/**
 * @Route("/dashboard")
 * @Route("/({companyName}/)dashboard")
 * @ParamConverter("company", class="AcmeDemoBundle:Company", options={"name" = "companyName"})
 */
public function showAction(Company $company = null)
{

}
```

The double route definition permit the default null company value

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But, while your answer shows a neat feature for having direct access to the entity based on the param passed, it does not help me preventing the definition of two routes that is what i asked for. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Yes, is only an improvement, not what you are looking for. The double routing definition as mentioned by @manolo is good for you?

Comment: yes, i already tried what @manolo suggested and it works. But, as i wrote, i'm trying and searching for something different and maybe better... (if exists)